# scala documentation tools - mid 2012 state of the art

Tags: scala

I liked Marginalia in the Clojure world. I came across this from Googling: http://blog.8-p.info/2011/02/03/scaladoc.html . What do people recommend? Or are people sticking with Scala Doc to keep with standards/what people are used to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaladoc for API's and [XRay](https://github.com/harrah/browse) ([example](http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala.html)) (produces browsable source code; it is abandoned but still awesome) are two mastadonts of scala documentation IMO. There is also [pamflet](http://pamflet.databinder.net/Pamflet.html) ([example](http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Try+Unfiltered.html)) and [port](http://circumflex.ru/api/2.0/circumflex-docco/src/main/scala/docco.scala.html) of [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/), but latter to my knowledge is not so popular.

Comment: XRay looks familiar from scalaz 6. I realized the cool part about xray is it can be used in parallel to scaladoc/etc. Docco is exactly what I had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Scala X-Ray is implemented as a compiler plug-in. Is it available for Scala 2.10?

Comment: @RandallSchulz well, [the latest commit message](https://github.com/harrah/browse/commit/46e7e8c68e44594c61a76f1b72af1b19c91a9050) is pretty eloquent (and yes, it is compiler plugin). Or there were some changes with plugin system in 2.10?